# Fragment and Adapter, how to pass switch position inside a listview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need to save with sharedPreferences a switch state(on/off). The switch is inside a listiview, which is inside a fragment. In the adapter I have a `setOnCheckedChangeListener`for the switch, just to change the color of the background of each item in the listview. The problem is that I don't want to use sharedPreferences inside the adapterClass(I don't think is a good practice).
Inside FragmentReport i wrote the method to load and save the state.

That's the method inside the "FragmentReport":

```
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.report_fragment, container, false);
    final ListView listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.report_lv);
    final View childView = 
    getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.report_list_view, null);
    paidCard = childView.findViewById(R.id.paid_cardview);
    paidSwitch = childView.findViewById(R.id.paid_switch);
     .......

     public void load_switch_state(){

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    paidSwitch.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("switch_check", true));
    if (paidSwitch.isChecked()) {
        // Set green background
        paidCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF2E7D32"));
    }

}

public void save_switch_state(Switch paidSwitch){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("switch_check", paidSwitch.isChecked());
    Log.v("saved", String.valueOf(paidSwitch.isChecked()));
    editor.apply();
}
```

Then, in my "ReportAdapter" , that's the getView method:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.report_list_view, null);
    TextView debtor = convertView.findViewById(R.id.debtor_tv);
    TextView receiver = convertView.findViewById(R.id.receiver);
    TextView difference = convertView.findViewById(R.id.difference_tv);
    final CardView paidCard = convertView.findViewById(R.id.paid_cardview);
    final Switch paidSwitch = convertView.findViewById(R.id.paid_switch);

    debtor.setText(debtorArray.get(position));
    receiver.setText(receiverArray.get(position));
    difference.setText(String.valueOf(differenceArray.get(position) + "€"));

    fragment.load_switch_state();
    paidSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                // Set green background
                paidCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF2E7D32"));

            }
            else{
                // Set blue background
                paidCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF3F51B5"));

            }
            fragment.save_switch_state(paidSwitch);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
```

The save method print "saved", but the the load method doesn't do anything.
Maybe I need to pass the position of the view?
That's a picture of the app:
[image]

The report_list_view.xml contains the switch with the id paid_switch
The report_fragment.xml contains the listview

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand you're question. But I think you are asking you don't want to `setChecked` if the Switch is not in the layout.

to avoid your error do this.

```
if(paidSwitch != null)
paidSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked){
            // Set green background
            paidCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF2E7D32"));
        }
        else{
            // Set blue background
            paidCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF3F51B5"));
        }
        ((GroupDetailActivity)context).save_switch_state(paidSwitch);
    }
});
```

and inside onCreate

```
    if(paidSwitch != null){
   paidSwitch.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("switch_check", false));
    if (paidSwitch.isChecked()) {
        // Set green background
        paidCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF2E7D32"));
        }
    }
```

We are adding a check here to only execute the code if paidSwitch isn't null

Edit:

```
getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.report_list_view, null);
paidCard = childView.findViewById(R.id.paid_cardview);
paidSwitch = childView.findViewById(R.id.paid_switch);
```

don't do this. manage this inside the ArrayAdapter and notifyDatasetHasChanged

Comment: hmm..no, maybe I wasn't clear enough. I need to save the state of my switch, and when I open the app again, I want to restore latest position of it. I update my question with code and photo

Comment: Okay why do you have 2 layouts? because one of the layout does not have the switch in it.

Comment: I just edit my question..could you take a look at it?

Comment: no, maybe my english is too bad. I solve my problem. I write the solution in a new answer

Comment: If you put the "-1" in my question, can you please remove it? Reading my answer you will understand that is not a duplicate

Comment: Thats what I told you to do in my answer. I told you to manage those inside the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this code inside my adapter:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.report_list_view, null);
    TextView debtor = convertView.findViewById(R.id.debtor_tv);
    TextView receiver = convertView.findViewById(R.id.receiver);
    TextView difference = convertView.findViewById(R.id.difference_tv);
    final CardView paidCard = convertView.findViewById(R.id.paid_cardview);
    final Switch paidSwitch = convertView.findViewById(R.id.paid_switch);

    debtor.setText(debtorArray.get(position));
    receiver.setText(receiverArray.get(position));
    difference.setText(String.valueOf(differenceArray.get(position) + "€"));

    paidSwitch.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("CheckValue" + position, false));
    if (paidSwitch.isChecked()) {
        // Set green background
        paidCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF2E7D32"));
    }
    paidSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // Set green background
                paidCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF2E7D32"));
                editor.putBoolean("CheckValue" + position, isChecked);
                editor.commit();

            } else {
                // Set blue background
                paidCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF3F51B5"));
                editor.putBoolean("CheckValue" + position, isChecked);
                editor.commit();

            }

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Now I save the state of my switch and after I close the app, it load properly the last state using sharedPreferences